# How to automatically execute "create table" statements generated with select statement?

Tags: sql-server, select, insert, linked-server

I have to move some data from our remote customer's mssql database to remote db2 database. On mssql server I own I created linked server to customer's source mssql database (I only have read permissions on) and created another linked server to remote db2 server.

I created some complex transformation, but for simplicity of this forum, lets simplify:

```
select
   'create table [remotedb2server].[remotedb2db].[myschema].'
   + name
   + "COLUMS HERE AND SOME COMPLEX TRANSFORMATION"
   from [remotemssqlserver].[remotemssql].[sys].[tables]
```

How to automatically execute above "create table" statements generated from select statement? I need a solution to be able to schedule it regularly in e.g. SQL Agent job.

I also have "drop table" select, "insert into" select etc and I would like to use the same logic.

Comment: Assign the result of that SELECT to a variable and pass it to `sp_executesql`

Answer (score 1):

This is known as dynamic SQL. You can execute arbitrary generated SQL by calling `sp_executesql` and passing in your command as a parameter. Keep in mind this has the potential to be very dangerous, as it exposes you to [sql injection vulnerabilities.](https://bobby-tables.com/)